# Wordpress panoramaic photos viewers

Tags: wordpress, three.js, 360-panorama-viewer, pannellum

am working on my Wordpress website, and came to this point where i want to add panoramic photos(360 Deg) to pages and posts,I've searched for plugins and it seems there is no  one can do the job properly, after a little search about tools which used for the the purpose as a whole i came to several viewers based on three.js,e.g pannellum,I've tried to upload js/css files to wp-content,then use wp_enqueue_script(),wp_enqueue_style() within function.php,and then use an iframe as demos of these tools showed, it didn't work, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Jetpack has a built-in 360/panoramic viewer. It's a pretty unknown feature but it works amazingly. The announcement post is here: https://en.blog.wordpress.com/2016/12/15/introducing-vr-and-360-content-for-all-wordpress-com-sites/

I would also suggest you read this for detailed instructions on how to upload and implement these: https://en.support.wordpress.com/embedding-360-photos-and-virtual-reality-vr-content/

Comment: i think this came late but thanks, Michael...i forgot to say i'm running on wordpress.org .